# PhpStorm: Converting folders encoding to another

Tags: encoding, utf-8, phpstorm

I have project, where are lots of files in **ISO-8859-15** and I need to convert them to **UTF-8**. If I change one file, it asks "Do you want to convert - plaplapla", if I say yes, important symbols wont become ???.

However, since my project file amount is HUGE, I cannot do that one by one. Changing encoding settings from project settings, it might change encoding to utf-8 but all the symbols will become ??? (thus no conversion).

So, how can I tell PhpStorm to convert all files into utf-8? Is it possible and if yes, how? What is the alternative method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to do this for whole folder at a time .. but it can be done for multiple files (e.g. all files in certain folder):

1. Select desired files in Project View panel
2. Use `File | File Encoding`
3. When asked -- make sure you choose "convert" and not just "read in another encoding".

You can repeat this procedure for each subfolder (still much faster than doing this for each file individually).

---

Another possible alternative is to use something like [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv) (or any other similar tool) and do it in terminal/console.

Comment: So, if it doesn't anything, it means it doesn't need convertion? Either way, thank you, I guess this is as close as I can get.

Comment: If encoding has to be "forced" multiselection does not work.. I have to select file by file..

Comment: @Delphine Did not had such cases myself so cannot give any comments (I rarely need to convert encodings -- using UTF-8 everywhere). But if it needs to be confirmed ("forced") then I guess you are right and it has to be one by one (which is inconvenient for sure if many files are affected).

Answer (score 5):

Watch out when opening the file inPHPStorm that you want to convert. In my case all the files were still encoded in ISO-8859 but opened in UTF-8 resulting in misspelled umlauts i.e. In this case direct conversion to UTF-8 is not possible.

If you encounter this do following:

1. Open the ISO-8859 file
2. Change file encoding dropdown (lower right corner) to ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15 and choose REOPEN
3. Misspellings will now disappear
4. Then change the encoding again (dropdown lower right corner), this time to UTF-8 and choose CONVERT
5. Now the file is properly encoded in UTF-8

cheers